# ThreeJs: Add a Gridhelper which always face the perspective camera

Tags: three.js

I have a `threejs` scene view containing a mesh, a perspective camera, and in which I move the camera with OrbitControls.

I need to add a measurement grid on a `threejs` view which "face" my perspective camera

It works on "start up" with the following code by applying a xRotation of Pi/2 on the grid helper

```js
window.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.01, 300 );
window.camera.position.z = 150;

window.grid1 = new THREE.GridHelper(500, ~~(500 * 2))
window.grid1.material.transparent = true;
window.grid1.material.depthTest = false;
window.grid1.material.blending = THREE.NormalBlending;
window.grid1.renderOrder = 100;
window.grid1.rotation.x = Math.PI / 2;
window.scene.add(window.grid1);

window.controls = new OrbitControls(window.camera, window.renderer.domElement );
window.controls.target.set( 0, 0.5, 0 );
window.controls.update();
window.controls.enablePan = false;
window.controls.enableDamping = true;
```

But once i start moving with orbitcontrol the grid helper don't stay align with the camera.

I try to use on the renderLoop

```js
window.grid1.quaternion.copy(window.camera.quaternion);
```

And

```js
window.grid1.lookAt(window.camera.position)
```

Which seems to work partially, gridhelper is aligned on the "floor" but not facing the camera

How can I achieve that?

Be gentle I'm starting with `threejs` :)

Comment: Add `grid1.geometry.rotateX( - Math.PI / 2 );` right after the grid is instantiated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bit of a hack, but you could wrap your grid in a `THREE.Group` and rotate it instead:

```js
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.01, 300 );
camera.position.z = 150;

const grid1 = new THREE.GridHelper(500, ~~(500 * 2));
grid1.material.transparent = true;
grid1.material.depthTest = false;
grid1.material.blending = THREE.NormalBlending;
grid1.renderOrder = 100;
grid1.rotation.x = Math.PI / 2;

const gridGroup = new THREE.Group();
gridGroup.add(grid1);
scene.add(gridGroup);

// ...
```

And then, in your render loop, you make your **group** face to the camera (and not the grid):

```js
gridGroup.lookAt(camera.position)
```

This works because it kind of simulates the behaviour of setting the normal in a `THREE.Plane`. The `GridHelper` is rotated to be perpendicular to the camera, and the it is wrapped in a group with no rotation. So by rotating the group, the grid will always be offset so that it is perpendicular to the camera.

Comment: Ho men thanks i will +10 you if i can haha